# How to modify Jenkins Git Build Data Revision to display the remote repo address

Tags: git, jenkins, revision

I have a Jenkins pipeline using the following code to checkout the project to build.

`checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "*/develop"]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'CloneOption', noTags: false, reference: '', shallow: false],[$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: "**"]], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'foobar', url: 'git@github.com:foo/bar.git']]])`

After the build is done, click the build record. [image]

Same as click the Status page. [image]

How do I make git Revision display the remote repo address, for example like git@github.com:foo/bar.git/tree/develop, instead of refs/remotes/origin/develop. 
[image]

Also in the Git Build Data page as shown below.[image][image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using `git remote -v`?

Comment: In pipeline script? It shows this                                                                         `origin git@github.com:foo/bar.git (fetch)
origin git@github.com:foo/bar.git (push)`

Comment: Does it? I can't see (in the question) where you mean.

Comment: Click `Console Output` or `控制台输出` there would have a complete log.

Comment: There seems to be an outstanding issue in Jenkins that would imply this isn't possible: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29326

Comment: @ kjhf thanks a lot